# equal sign with haskell literals

Tags: haskell, equality, literals

What exactly happens in GHCi when I load a file with a line that says: 0=1 ?

I was expecting that this would give an error but it doesn't seem to do anything at all. Does it do anything?

I assume it's equivalent in GHCi to just saying "let 0=1". What does that do?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The `0` in your `let` binding is actually a pattern match on the literal `0`. I wasn't sure what was going on at first too, but you can confirm this by using strict pattern matching like  so:

```
Prelude> :set -XBangPatterns 
Prelude> let !0 = 1 in 0
*** Exception: <interactive>:13:5-10: Non-exhaustive patterns in pattern binding
```

Answer (score 9):

If you give the failing pattern match a name `x`, you can also force it like so:

```
x @ 0 = 1
main = print x
```

Which produces the error:

```
FILE.hs: /path/to/FILE.hs:1:5-13: Irrefutable pattern failed for pattern x@0
```

Answer (score 3):

`0=1` is just a pattern binding.

[Haskell 2010  Language Report describes](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch4.html#x10-620004)

```
4.4.3 Function and Pattern Bindings

decl    →   (funlhs | pat) rhs

funlhs  →   var apat { apat }
    |   pat varop pat
    |   ( funlhs ) apat { apat }

rhs     →   = exp [where decls]
    |   gdrhs [where decls]

gdrhs   →   guards = exp [gdrhs]

guards  →   | guard1, …, guardn         (n ≥ 1)

guard   →   pat
```

> We distinguish two cases within this syntax: **a pattern binding** occurs when the left hand side is a **pat**; otherwise, the binding is called **a function binding**. Either binding may appear at the top-level of a module or within a where or let construct.

Patterns have this syntax:

```
pat     →   lpat qconop pat         (infix constructor)
    |   lpat

lpat    →   apat
    |   - (integer | float)         (negative literal)
    |   gcon apat1 … apatk      (arity gcon  =  k, k ≥ 1)

apat    →   var [ @ apat]       (as pattern)
    |   gcon        (arity gcon  =  0)
    |   qcon { fpat1 , … , fpatk }      (labeled pattern, k ≥ 0)
    |   literal
    |   _       (wildcard)
    |   ( pat )         (parenthesized pattern)
    |   ( pat1 , … , patk )         (tuple pattern, k ≥ 2)
    |   [ pat1 , … , patk ]         (list pattern, k ≥ 1)
    |   ~ apat      (irrefutable pattern)

fpat    →   qvar = pat
```

Language Report also states

> A pattern binding binds variables to values. A simple pattern binding has form p  =  e. The pattern p is matched “lazily” as an irrefutable pattern, as if there were an implicit ~ in front of it.

So, `0` in `0=1` is just a pattern. In essence, `0=1` and `x=1` are the same thing. They are both pattern bindings.
The pattern is irrefutable, `0=1` does not fail, thus no error occurred and nothing happened.

If we have the following top level declaration. Something will happen.

```
x@(Just y) | z /= Nothing = Just 1
  where
    z = Just 0
```

`x` and `y` are binding to `Just 1` and 1.